# NSTimer is not getting stopped

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, nstimer

I am trying to stop the timer. My problem is when I try to stop the timer the value of timer is nil and it is not getting invalidated. if there any way to stop the timer except this ?

My code is like

timer is defined in header file - and also synthesized.

```
if([str_Message isEqualToString:ON] // if the command to start timer

{


 if(!timer) 

{

tmr_CallWebService = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:Time_TracingInterval target:ClassTracing selector:@selector(startLocationTracing) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]retain];

}

//to stop timer

else if([str_Message isEqualToString:OFF])
{
if(timer)

{

[timer invalidate];
timer = nil;

}
```

Please help me out... thanks in advance

Comment: Where do you set timer?  Is it retained?

Comment: @progrmr I forgot to write.. i just edited my code.

Comment: but where do you start your timer? Maybe you just want to rename `tmr_CallWebService` to `timer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[str_Message isEqualToString:ON]` should be like this `[str_Message isEqualToString:@"ON"]`. similarly for the comparison with OFF. Use `@"OFF"`.

Comment: That is not issue, as the condition is getting true...  but the timer value is nil is the issue. when the off command is received

Comment: Well, if  `ON` is declared as `NSString* ON = @"ON";` and OFF similarly, there would be no problem with this part.

Comment: @iPhone Fun: Are `OFF` and `ON` defined as constants?

Comment: Then if you have a retain property on the timer then use the getter method to invalidate it.

Comment: @evan Yes these are string constants

Comment: @praveen Can you tell me how to use the Getter method as I am not able to get your idea.

Comment: You can go with @Paul Tiarks answer. When you use the synthesize on a property declared a getter and setter is already created. When you alloc to this variable you need to reference it using self like self.time = /*alloc timer*/ which calls the setter. Same thing when you want to dealloc it, use the getter and set it to nil.

Comment: I go the solution - I just put my timer in the AppDelegate.. and immediately I got the timer values and issues is resolved.

Answer (score 4):

I think you just need to replace `tmr_CallWebService` with `timer`.

Answer (score 2):

If you've got a property declared for the timer, you should use it.  For instance, if your timer is defined as `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *myTimer;` you should refer to it as self.myTimer and set it using that setter and invalidate it later using the accessor.

It looks like you're not setting tmr_CallWebService to your timer ivar at any place so you're just leaking and losing the reference.